# UAgent CodeIgniter Library Installation Errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

The codeigniter library, UAgent, is giving me errors on installation. Here is the error:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: Missing argument 1 for Shared_Framework::__construct(), 
called in /system/libraries/Loader.php on line 928 and defined

    Filename: libraries/Shared_Framework.php
```

This happens when I execute the following code:

```
$this->load->library('Shared_Framework');
$this->load->library('Uagent');
```

This is what the manual says to do but I can't figure out how to fix the error. Here is the link to the library just in case: http://www.vvvlad.com/resources/uagent

Comment: Can you perhaps post the code for the Share_Framework constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor requires that you pass a parameter, just load the library like this instead:

```
$this->load->library('Shared_Framework',$params);
```

Comment: Thank You, this worked. Sending in an empty $params array did the trick.